# Refactor protected base class dependency for test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, refactoring

This problem comes from a real world project, which uses the "provide protected interface in base class" pattern very often.

Here's a small example:

```
class UntouchableBase
{
protected: //cannot be called from outer class
    int GetValue() { return 42;}//not virtual

    //this class has many many more "protected interface" methods
};

class HeavyWeightClassIWantToTest: public UntouchableBase
{
public:
//  VeryHeavyClassIWantToTest(...) {} //ignore the creation issue for a heavy weight object here

    void MethodThatNeedsTest()
    {
        //calc some values
        int result = GetValue(); 
        //do some other stuff
    }
};
```

**I'm looking for a fast, mostly noninvasive refactoring, to replace the GetValue dependency.**
Extracting Methods and adding new class is allowed for `HeavyWeightClassIWantToTest`

@UPDATE: Test,to illustrate the issue

```
TEST(EnsureThat_MyMethodThatNeedsTestDoesSthSpecial)
{
    HeavyWeightClassIWantToTest sut = MakeSut();

    sut.MethodThatNeedsTest(); //should call a mocked / replaced GetValue()
}
```

Hint: Currently we're using a linker seam to replace the `UntouchableBase` implementation for testing purposes.

Please provide coded examples.

Comment: How untouchable is `UntouchableBase`?  Can you modify the header file, or not even that?  How about `class TestableBase : public UntouchableBase`, and then derive `HeavyWeightClass` from `TestableBase` ?

Comment: Change at UntouchableBase comes at very high cost. You can't overload directly, because the GetValue() method is not virtual.

Comment: I think you mean "override" rather than "overload", but provided nobody is doing `pUntouchableBase->GetValue()`, you can hide the function with a version in the intermediate class.

Answer (score 1):

You have the template way:

```
template <typename Base>
class HeavyWeightClassIWantToTestGeneric: public Base
{
public:
    // ...

    void MethodThatNeedsTest()
    {
        //calc some values
        int result = this->GetValue(); // use `this->` for dependent name
        //do some other stuff
    }
};

// For production
using HeavyWeightClassProduction = HeavyWeightClassIWantToTestGeneric<UntouchableBase>;

// For Test
using HeavyWeightTest = HeavyWeightClassIWantToTestGeneric<TestBase>;
```

Comment: +1 for the `this->` overload! Unfortunately the creation of HeavyWeightClass in production code is done by the system. And there are many many HeavyWeight classes, which are handled all the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The brute-force solution could be:
`#define protected public`

More cleaner mechanism is to make the test friend of the `UntouchableBase`. This allows the test code (and just the test code) access to the privates, protecteds, whilst protecting them from everything else.

What one should do is use a compiler define for unit testing:

```
#ifdef UNIT_TESTING
friend void UnitTestFn()
#endif
```

If you are using Google Test, you can use [FRIEND_TEST](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#testing-private-code) to declare your test fixtue as a friend to the class under test.

Comment: Does not help at all. How to replace the GetValue call?